# Use 2 objects in a controller function

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data

I am new in SpringBoot.

I have 2 objects

```
public class Phone {
    private long id;
    private String phone;
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
}

public class MailID {
    private long id;
    private String mail;
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getMail() {
        return mail;
    }
    public void setMail(String mail) {
        this.mail = mail;
    }
}
```

I have created a controller to get these objects.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/person")
public class PersonController {

    @RequestMapping(
            value = "/mail", 
            method = RequestMethod.POST, 
            consumes = "application/json",
            produces = "application/json"
        )
    public String getMail(@RequestBody MailID mail) {
        System.out.println(mail.getId()+"  "+mail.getMail());
        return mail.getMail();
    }

    @RequestMapping(
            value = "/phone", 
            method = RequestMethod.POST, 
            consumes = "application/json",
            produces = "application/json"
        )
    public String getPhone(@RequestBody Phone phone) {
        System.out.println(phone.getId()+"  "+phone.getPhone());
        return phone.getPhone();
    }


    @RequestMapping(
            value = "/info", 
            method = RequestMethod.POST, 
            consumes = "application/json",
            produces = "application/json"
        )
    public String mysqlToEs(  @RequestBody MailID mail, @RequestBody Phone phone) {
        System.out.println(mail.getMail()+"  "+phone.getPhone());
        return mail.getMail()+"  "+phone.getPhone();
    }
}
```

This commands works fine. It accept the MailID object values perfectly.

```
curl -X POST -d '{"id":1, "mail":"abc@yahoo.com"}' -H "Content-type:application/json"  http://localhost:8084/person/mail
```

It accept the Phone object values perfectly.

```
curl -X POST -d '{"id":1, "phone":"3333212"}' -H "Content-type:application/json"  http://localhost:8084/person/phone
```

Now i want to pass both MailID and Phone values in a single POST request. I tried the following curl request. BUt it didnt work.

```
curl -X POST -d '{"phone":{"id":1, "phone":"3333212"}}' -H "Content-type:application/json"  http://localhost:8084/person/info
```

I have read that we can solve this issue sby creating a new object with fields as `MailId` and `Phone`. Is that the proper way of doing? Is there any other way, so that I can access both the object parameters in a single function itself?

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure but try with passing map as function argument. Then you will need to construct object manually from parsing json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to create a new object that holds the other two. Something like this:

```
class MyNewObjectRequest{
private MailID mailId;
private Phone phone;
... some getters/setters
}
```

Then you need to change the controller to receive the holder.

```
@RequestMapping(
            value = "/info", 
            method = RequestMethod.POST, 
            consumes = "application/json",
            produces = "application/json"
        )
    public String mysqlToEs(  @RequestBody MyNewObjectRequest rq) {
        System.out.println(rq.getEmailId().getMail()+"  "+rq.getPhone().getPhone());
        return rq.getEmailId().getMail()+"  "+rq.getPhone().getPhone();
    }
```

And the request json looks like this:

```
{"emailId" : {"id":1, "mail":"abc@yahoo.com"}, "phone" : {"id":1, "phone":"3333212"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have more than one object in the request body, you will have to use the

```
@RequestPart
```

annotation instead of

```
@RequestBody
```

for this to work, you have to name the fields (easy if it is an HTML form, not sure how to do that in curl).

one thing to consider is that this is bad style for REST APIs, because it would be asymmetric (one POST to create, but two different methods to GET). if you create one object with both fields, it is symmetric again.

because of that, i would consider NOT doing two create operations in one call.

Comment: i tried to do using @RequestPart.. but i didnt get the curl command,, so i created an object with both fields

Comment: that's the nicer way anyways. in html, the @RequestPart corresponds to "encoding=multipart/form-data"